# Ubuntu GNOME live not loading properly on MacBook Pro

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, macbook-pro

Before installing Ubuntu gnome 17.04 on a MacBook Pro (mid 2012), I wanted to try the live version from a USB stick.

The problem here is that after the system​ loads, I just see the default gnome wallpaper, without the top bar or anything else. Also, if I press  I don't see the window modifier with all the apps, but rather only the vignetted background image. If I suspend the laptop by pressing the power button and resume it, I see the lock screen without date and time.

Loading the system with `nomodeset` option also seems not to solve anything, as the system will then hang during boot.

What can I do?

Answer (score -1):

I learned about the `gpt` kernel option from the guide below.  There is an open source, but paid for binaries system available called Mac Linux USB Loader at https://www.sevenbits.io/mlul/ .  It can help you generate the live USB stick, and gives you some easy kernel modifications on boot.  I'm sure you can do this directly off the default installer too, but I'm not sure exactly how.

It works for the live boot from a USB stick for me (both for Ubuntu GNOME and regular Ubuntu).  For some reason, I haven't been able to get the install that I do using Ubuntu GNOME to work, but the install from regular Ubuntu DOES work.  I've been experimenting with getting GNOME to install after getting the initial system up and running, but so far I keep getting a black screen after rebooting once I've installed `ubuntu-gnome-desktop`.

The guide I mentioned lead me to the Mac Linux USB Loader is here: https://medium.com/@racter/how-to-install-ubuntu-16-04-on-a-retina-macbook-11-2-74e7779c0e47 .

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/709239)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback; I've tried to address your comments.  :)